# How can I overide the base class method with new information in a derivede class?

Tags: python

I'm asked the following:

Given the base class Book, define a derived class called Encyclopedia. Within the derived Encyclopedia class, define a print_info() method that overrides the Book class' print_info() method by printing not only the title, author, publisher, and publication date, but also the edition and number of volumes.

Example:

If Input

```
Enter Book Information
Enter title: The Hobbit
Enter author: J. R. R. Tolkien
Enter publisher: George Allen & Unwin
Enter publication date: 21 September 1937
Enter title: The Illustrated Encyclopedia of the Universe

Enter Encyclopedia Information
Enter author: James W. Guthrie
Enter publisher: Watson-Guptill
Enter publication date: 2001
Enter edition: 2nd
Enter number of volumes: 1
```

Output

```
Book Information: 
   Book Title: The Hobbit
   Author: J. R. R. Tolkien
   Publisher: George Allen & Unwin
   Publication Date: 21 September 1937
Encyclopedia Information: 
   Book Title: The Illustrated Encyclopedia of the Universe
   Author: James W. Guthrie
   Publisher: Watson-Guptill
   Publication Date: 2001
   Edition: 2nd
   Number of Volumes: 1
```

I've tried messing with it but I just keep printing the books info twice?
Here's my code

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, publisher, publication_date):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.publication_date = publication_date

    def print_info(self):
        print('Book Information:')
        print('   Book Title:', self.title)
        print('   Author:', self.author)
        print('   Publisher:', self.publisher)
        print('   Publication Date:', self.publication_date)


class Encyclopedia(Book):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       title, author, publisher, publication_date, edition, num_volumes
    def __init__(self, title, author, publisher, publication_date, edition, num_volumes):
        Book.__init__(self, title, author, publisher, publication_date)
        self.edition = edition
        self.num_volumes = num_volumes

    # TODO: Define a print_info() method that overrides the print_info()
    #       in the Book class
    def print_info(self):
        print('Encyclopedia Information:')
        print('   Book Title:', self.title)
        print('   Author:', self.author)
        print('   Publisher:', self.publisher)
        print('   Publication Date:', self.publication_date)
        print('   Edition:', self.edition)
        print('   Number of Volumes:', self.num_volumes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Enter Book Information')
    title = input('Enter title: ')
    author = input('Enter author: ')
    publisher = input('Enter publisher: ')
    publication_date = input('Enter publication date: ')
    print('\nEnter Encyclopedia Information')
    e_title = input('Enter title: ')
    e_author = input('Enter author: ')
    e_publisher = input('Enter publisher: ')
    e_publication_date = input('Enter publication date: ')
    edition = input('Enter edition: ')
    num_volumes = int(input('Enter number of volumes: '))

    #TODO: Creat a book instance and call the print_info method    
    book = Book(title, author, publisher, publication_date)
    book.print_info()
    #TODO: Creat a encyclopedia instance and call the print_info method
    enc = Encyclopedia(title, author, publisher, publication_date, edition, num_volumes)
    enc.print_info()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating `enc` object you are passing same arguments as the `book` object. It should be `enc = Encyclopedia(e_title, e_author, e_publisher, e_publication_date, edition, num_volumes)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your parameters for [`Encyclopedia`](https://pypi.org/project/encyclopedia/) as:

```
enc = Encyclopedia(e_title, e_author, e_publisher, e_publication_date, edition, num_volumes)
enc.print_info()
```

Because you are sending same parameters for both the classes, it is printing them twice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it looks like that is because you didn't define all of the properties with an attribute. It looks like you are still missing author, publisher, and publication_date. Also delete line 20. I think that would be line 20 but it's the part where you have Book.**init**(self, title, author, publisher, publication_date). Delete that whole line of code and then just define the properties values of author, publisher, and publication_date just like the same way you did for edition and num_volume and it should work then. Everything else looks good!